# Can we add "no research" flag, or this can be achieved otherwise?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation

I saw questions with **no** or **almost no** research effort. Can we add  "**no research**" flag on those questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's hardly achieving anything in site's mechanics.

If you think question is especially lacking in quality — downvote:

> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post [...]
>
> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down